# How to access a value in a list of nested dicts and lists in a python tree

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have built a tree in python with each node consisting of a list as `[{}, []]`.  When I populate the tree if there is not a full phrase the inner list does not exist.  I am at a point where I want to access the values from a node that looks like

```
[{
    "AH": [{
        "K": [{
            "IH": [{
                "JH": [{
                    "IY": [{
                        "T": [{
                            "AH": [{
                                "R": [{
                                    "T": [{
                                        "S": [{},
                                            [954557]
                                        ]
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "F": [{
            "T": [{
                "K": [{
                    "AE": [{
                        "T": [{},
                            [0]
                        ]
                    }]
                }]
            }],
            "M": [{
                "AH": [{
                    "AY": [{
                        "R": [{
                            "T": [{},
                                [427266]
                            ]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I need someway to iterate through and grab every number. I realize a recursive method is needed however I have no idea how to go about it.

Also the reason it is built with lists is a result that the serialization I am going for would take too long with making custom classes.

Comment: show us what you've tried.. (and explain why that blob of data is a minimal example..)

Comment: So what happens is I am looking for the closest sentence to rhyme with a given phrase.  What the node displayed is the 3 phrases that are the closest to the given input.  I have over 999k phrases so there is a lot of data to pour through.  The keys represent phonetic representations of the phrase.    Where my issue arises is the fact that I am dealing with not only nested dicts but dicts and lists.  I try to get to a point where they key is {} then grab the list but I can't even find a way to iterate to that point.

Comment: Can you  find a solution if you only have 1 phrase?  How about 2?  Hint: to visualize the data structure better, you could use `import json;print json.dumps(data, indent=4)`  (then you'll see that you've mismatched parens..)

Comment: ps: since your terminals are `[{}, [int]]` and your non-terminals are `[{key: [{child-nodes}]]`, you could simplify to non-terminals `{key: {child-nodes}}` and terminals `{key: int}` (or `{key: [ints]}` if there are more than one int at the terminals).  This will simplify your code greatly.

Comment: [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) ?